# Reduce Hamiltonian Path Decision Problem To Hamiltonian Cycle Decision Problem

Tags: np-complete, hamiltonian-path

Person **A** requires that he determine whether or not a particular graph **G = (V,E)** has a **Hamiltonian path** from vertex **a** to vertex **b**.

His colleague Person **B** has implemented a function that takes an undirected graph **G = (V,E)** and returns true iff G has a **hamiltonian cycle**. Person **B**  said you can use my function to get your answer, just make sure to add an edge that connects **a** with **b**.

Give an example that shows that the answer returned by Person **B**'s function might not coincide with Person **A** 's original problem.

In other words, simply adding an edge between **a** and **b** is insufficient for reducing HP to HC decision problem.